# How to make a button that will go to the previous menu in ncurses

Tags: c++, ncurses

I am pretty new to c++ and ncurses, so sorry if my question is weird or obvious.
I managed to make a simple tui program that will do various tasks, my problem is that I have no back functionality or something that would loop the program.

I want to be able to go back to the main menu after accessing one of the submenus and I want to make the program repeat after it's done so I won't have to keep opening it over and over, so do you have any solutions that I can apply?

Thank you in advance

This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{ 
int i=0;
string input;
        initscr();
    noecho();
    cbreak();
    curs_set(0);
int yMax, xMax;
getmaxyx(stdscr, yMax, xMax);

WINDOW * menuwin = newwin (0, xMax, 0, 0);
leaveok(menuwin, true);
refresh();
wrefresh(menuwin);

keypad(menuwin, true);

string choices[4] = {"Youtube","Music","Anime","Games"};
int choice;
int highlight = 0;
int option = 0;


while(1)
{
    for (i=0;i < 4; i++)
{       
    if(i == highlight)
        wattron(menuwin, A_REVERSE);
        mvwprintw(menuwin, i+1, 1, choices[i].c_str());
        wattroff(menuwin, A_REVERSE);


 }
choice = wgetch(menuwin);

switch(choice)
{
case KEY_UP:
  highlight--;
  if(highlight == -1)
    highlight = 3;  
  break;
case KEY_DOWN:
  highlight++;
  if(highlight == 4)
      highlight = 0;
  break;
default:
break;
}
if(choice == 10)
{
    break;

}

}
werase(menuwin);
switch(highlight)
{
    case 0:
        {
         menu2();
      break;
        }
    case 1:
        {
      menu3();
      break;
        }
    case 2:
        {
      menu4();
      break;
        }
    case 3:
      {
          menu2();
      }
    default:
     break;
}
endwin();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try solving a simple problem first: your "main menu" is just `std::cout << "Hello\n";` and your "submenu" consists of `std::cout << "world!\n";`. Everything else about this program is the same, so the overall program is now, what, ten lines of code? Now, add the trivial logic that "returns to the main menu", as you put it. Then, when you accomplish that, simply make the same change to your current program. Mission accomplished!

Comment: Thank you! I made a ```do while``` statement that would loop the menu if a switch variable is triggered, from there I just add another option called ```Back``` that would change that variable to a value that triggers the loop.